# (OBJECTIVE C) Is TABLEVIEW CELL IDENTIFIER important?

Tags: ios, tableview, cell

I am using OBJECTIVE C
I am implementing 8 custom cells
I know that the cell identifier should be set as many as the number of cell types.
Even if I code the identifier as 1, it works.
Is this normal? Why should I set the identifier separately for each cell TYPE??

Comment: From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/configuring_the_cells_for_your_table): `Reuse identifiers facilitate the creation and recycling of your table’s cells.` ... So the question is: why would you ***not*** want to give each different cell class its own identifier?

Comment: yes. 
No error occurs even if 8 cells type have the same identifier
However, I don't understand why each should specify a different identifier

Comment: because.... ***`Reuse identifiers facilitate the creation and recycling of your table’s cells.`***

Answer (score 0):

For each unique custom cell, it is vital to declare its unique identifier.
Whereas if all the 8 cells have similar functionality then you may declare same identifier for all the cells.